# How create this native query in JPA?

Tags: mysql, jpa, jpa-2.0

I have this query in MySQL :

```
SELECT genre 
FROM genre g, person_genre pg, rfid rfid, room room 
WHERE 
    pg.id_genre = g.id and 
    pg.id_person = rfid.id_person and 
    rfid.id = room.id_rfid 
GROUP BY 
    g.genre
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1;
```

> output: Blues, Rock

Which works pretty fine in mysql query browser, so I'm trying to use this same query in my jsf 2 with jpa so I did this :

```
public List<String> getListAverageGenres(){
        return em.createNativeQuery("SELECT genre " +
                                    "FROM genre g, person_genre pg, rfid rfid, room room " +
                                    "WHERE " +
                                        "pg.id_genre = g.id and " +
                                        "pg.id_person = rfid.id_person and " +
                                        "rfid.id = room.id_rfid " +
                                    "GROUP BY " +
                                        "g.genre " +
                                    "HAVING COUNT(*) > 1").getResultList();
    }
```

> Output : Blues, Rock, Blues, Rock, Blues, Rock

I don't know why the same query it's been calling more than one time.
I think is because it's native query so I'm trying to build a jpa query and see if it works.

Comment: Running the same query in mysql and as a native query should give the same results.

Comment: @beerbajay it gives the same result, but it makes the same query 3 times in jpa, why is that ?

Comment: It sounds like some other code is invoking `getListAverageGenres` multiple times; the query itself should return the same two rows. Try using the debugger to see when the method is getting called.

Answer (score 0):

You can try with

```
SELECT DISTINCT genre
```